# mysql bug database error

Tags: mysql

Why is that when I search a row in my database, it ended up 0 results? In fact, there are rows  that meet my search criterion when I view them manually, but the search button doesnt work as it is. Heres how

[image]

you can see there are rows that have '0000-00-00 00:00:00' in them, but when I used the search feature, it ended up like this:

[image]

take note that Im entering it in the right field which is 'AcctStopTime'.

TIA

Comment: found the error, its in the Limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're searching with `LIMIT 30 , 30`.

That will cause there to be no results if there as less than 30 results total. Try `LIMIT 0 , 30` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze your query, you can see `LIMIT 30, 30`.

What it says is, extract 30 rows, from the 30th position. So, if you do not have any records more than or beyond 30, then your query will return an empty set.

Next thing you might want to check is the `WHERE` condition

If the given values does not match any field it will not return any records also.